Any idea what this iron or iron-like block of material is on the bottom of an outside utility room door?
I was planning on changing out the door sweep on this door, which goes to utility room on the side of my patio and is not accessible from the house.
At the bottom of the door on the opposite of the hinge side there is what appears to be a rusted iron block.  At first I thought it was the remnant of some kind of nest, as mud daubers try to build nests in the door frame from time to time, but it is magnetic and very dense and would not just fall off when I hit it.  I filed off some of it to make it smoother, but it started out probably around a half inch thick and sticks out past the side of the door. There is no latch or anything in the door frame that it would go in.  It was brittle and seems incredibly worn, though the rest of the door is in excellent shape.
Any ideas what it could be?  It is not attached to the door sweep. I am planning on just spraying it with some Rust-oleum and letting it be.
I should also note that this is a townhouse, and my neighbors have an identical door going to their utility room.  Their door has a little dark area on the bottom where something similar to what I have could easily fit, but nothing is there.


Looks like a rusting steel door.

I agree with crip659. It looks like rust on a steel door. Your plan for the Rustoleum  and letting it be would be frugal and prudent if you monitor it for future damage.

I assumed it was rust, but the thing is, which I forgot to mention in the original post, is that before i filed it down a bit it was in a square shape that stuck out distinctly about a half inch from the the rest of the side of the door, like it was something attached there on its own.  There is no rust anywhere else on the door. It almost made me wonder if it was some kind of magnetic latch or something.

Probably just reinforcement against wear.

Good thinking, thanks.

That is a steel door with a shoe sweep.   Not really what weird thing you are referring to.   The door looks very repairable.
